# Parse JSON Array With Special Characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am simply trying to parse through an array key=>value pair that has a .0 in it. Below is the JSON I'm trying to parse through.

```
{message: "The given data was invalid.", errors: {…}}
errors:
    step1.0: Array(1)
        0: "Invalid response."
```

I'm trying to get "Invalid response" to log in the console. I get caught up when I try

```
errors.step1.0[0]
```

...it doesn't like the ".0". I have tried to escape it with "\" and have tried using 0 in a string, but nothing is working. I'm sure it's a simple syntax issue.

Thank you!

Comment: That is not JSON you're showing. And "an array key=>value" is called an object, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  "step1.0": 'test'
};

console.log(obj['step1.0']);
```

You can use bracket notation